# Answering a question with Multivariate analysis - benefits of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis

I'm doing an medical analysis examining the relationship between 20odd variables with a particular patient outcome. I've always run a multivariate analysis to answer these sort of questions, with the aim of developing a predictive model for identifying "at risk" patients.

I'm trained in traditional statistics, and wonder if there's differences in machine learning algorithm. I can't find alot of information examining the exact methods that a ML algorithm uses, and wonder if it adds much above a well fitted traditional Multivariate analysis.

Thanks for any input!

Cheers
Sing

Answer (score 1):

roughly speaking ML models are automated non linear statistical models. ie in a 'traditional' statistical approach, you would add/iterate over a few well chosen non linear transformations of data, interactions etc and fit using linear model. a typical ML model, eg xgboost, builds trees to capture the interactions and nonlinearities automatically. ( and afaik given a fixed,trained xg boost model you can essentially convert it into a linear regression model, by adding each tree as a non linear transform/interaction of the input - with coefficients representing leaves of the tree.)

Answer (score 0):

You aim at developing a predictive model and you want to identify patients who are at risk of outcome A. Your goal is to assign each patient a probability of outcome A.

This kind of problem is especially well suited for machine learning. It is a classification problem (will my patient get outcome A or not) that can be addressed easily with a logistic regression or with more complex models (like neural networks). In a logistic regression, your output would be `p = sigmoid(a0 + a1*X1 + ... + an*Xn)` where `X1, ..., Xn` are your variables and `a0, ..., an` are coefficients found by your algorithm to minimize your evaluation metric (may it be logloss or area under ROC).

I don't know how it compares to Multivariate Analysis though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - the multivariate analysis method I will use is likely a logistic regression model. Is it fair to say that with the same data set, a ML algorithm based upon log regression will give me the same predictive capability as a model generated using something like SAS/SPSS?